# Is using "on the show" wrong here?

Tags: meaning

Is using "on the show" wrong here? I want to say "on to show" to mean "revealed on the show", but obviously it's not correct to use it to mean that, but I am wondering what exactly it could mean in certain contexts.

For example:

> He rigged the paternity test on the Jeff Springer Show.

Does the sentence imply that the paternity test was taken on the show, or can it mean numerous things like that the results of the test were revealed on the show?

Comment: [do something] "on the show" really can be looked up. Also, you are misusing to rig. That too can be looked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is ambiguous.

All that is clear from the construction is that the rigging took place on the show - that's to say, during the course of the show, whether live or recorded.

Whether the tests were conducted during the course of the show is not clear from the grammar but almost impossible in practice, given the scientific procedures involved.

So the possibilities are that a specimen was taken during the show (but the results would not have been immediately available if this was the case) or that the results were rigged (or faked) but your sentence leaves this open.

The expression **on the show** fits perfectly in this context.

Comment: I guess "on the show" can modify "rig" or can modify "The Jeff Springer Show", right?